# Is it possible to detect end of promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, q

Is it possible to add a handle to a promise such that it gets executed at the end of the promise chain. I know there is `done()` and `finally()`, but they execute after the *current* promise is resolved/fails, not the whole chain.

EDIT:
The actual case is:
Basically I have a function allocating a db connection and executing a db query, and returns a promise that gets resolved when the query completes, passing the connection and result. The function also sets up a query method on the connection  that returns another promise, so queries can be chained on the same db connection by calling the query method from a then() handler and returning the returned promise. The db connection has to be free once all handles are done. Currently I just require the user of the function to manually free the connection in the last then(), and I auto-free it in error handlers.

Comment: What do mean by whole chain? Can you please explain with an example?

Comment: Could you use `all()`? I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do without an example.

Comment: Question edited to add the actual case

Comment: You should add what you are really trying to do

Comment: @Esailija 10$ says it's using. Edit: nvm, OP already confirmed it's `Promise.using`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be blunt: **No**.

there is no way to detect the end promise chain. Especially since you can add things later:

```
var original = delay(500).then(delay(100);
// when is original done?
setTimeout(function(){
    var p = original.then(function(){ return delay(1000);});
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) p = p.then(function(){ return delay(1000); });
});
```

The only way is to do something close is to nest:

```
myPromise().then(function(){
    return promise2().then(promise3).then(promise4);
}).finally(function(){
    // all promises done here
});
```

---

Edit after clarification:

Bluebird promises experimentally allow `Promise.using`, which would let you dispose connections like you'd want. This is somewhat similar to `using(` in C# except asynchronous.

Here's an example from the API:

```
function getConnection(){
    return pool.getConnectionAsync().disposer(function(conn,out){
        conn.releaseToPool();
    });
}

Promise.using(getConnection(), function(connection) {
   return connection.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
}).then(function(rows) {
    console.log(rows);
});
```

In this case, the connection closes as soon as the query finishes (that is, the inner chaining is complete). The big advantage is that you don't have to *remember* to use `.end` is you get connections with `using`.

Official support will land in 2.0 soon.

Comment: `disposer("close")` is not supported anyomre :P

Comment: @Esailija is too https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/promise-using/src/using.js#L158 :P

Comment: Classic petka, deleting that deprecated branch to win a comment argument in Stack Overflow :P